# Can I bind keys in a Tcl shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, tcl, bindkey

In my tcshrc I can set *ctrl+right_arrow/left_arrow* to skip a word forward/backward in the terminal.

I want to set the same behavior in a tcl shell (for example in Fusion Compiler or in Prime Time).
Can it be done?

In tcshrc I used:

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word 
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
```

**bindkey** doesn't work in a tcl shell

Answer (score 1):

The Tcl shell (whether as `tclsh`, or as `wish` on some platforms) uses the simple cooked mode for handling input. That doesn't allow any sort of complex binding of the sort you describe; at the point it receives input from the terminal, a full line has already been entered. Exactly what editing is supported there is up to the provider of the terminal implementation, but it is often extremely simple.

You can try a few alternatives. *Some* of these I have tried:

- You can use the `rlwrap` to wrap a readline implementation around the Tcl shell. I've no experience with this, but I know others have done it. (There might be other ways to do readline/editline library integrations too.)
- You can use Tkcon, assuming you've got a GUI available. This works pretty well in my experience and gives you full line editing already. (It can also do a lot of other things, such as attaching to existing processes.)
- In Tcl 8.7, you can `chan configure` the `stdin` channel to be in `raw` mode and get access to the actual keys pressed (though you also need to handle showing the user what's going on, if relevant). I've no idea if anyone has wrapped that to make an editable command line system, but it should be possible.

Comment: I have experience with rlwrap.  

I have a command line alias for tclsh like this:   `readline -c tclsh8.6` .   This enables the up/down keys for command history, `ctrl-a` and `ctrl-e` to move the cursor to beginning/end of the command, etc.

Comment: "me too" for rlwrap: shell => `alias tclsh='rlwrap tclsh'`

Comment: I installed rlwrap. now what?